# Monitor JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is it possible, to monitor all JavaScript events in the browser?
For example, which functions has been called, which parameters have been passed in which js-file?

In my case I have some obfuscated code and need to find out which functions are being called when I perform an action.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: There's no natural way to do it. You can only detect fatal errors, like, `property or object does not exists` and the like

Answer (score 2):

[TraceGL](https://trace.gl/) codeflow visualiser may be what you're looking for.

Comment: These days tracegl can be found here: https://github.com/traceglMPL/tracegl but I think that project is dead. No activity and I can not read the text generated by the code in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

You want to monitor javascript events, may be this is what you want:

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. But I need something like a monitor or a log, where all performed actions are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but I think Firebug's [profiler](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Profiler) and [debugger](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging) will give you the information you're looking for.